# Network segmentation allow for scale-out applications?

Tags: networking

Can we use network segmentation for scale-out web servers? For example, we have 192.168.15.0/24 subnet for all our web servers. If we create multiple /24 subnets in private address space, can we achieve web application scale out? If the private subnet IP resources is exhausted, how do you scale out the web servers?

Comment: There's 65536 separate IP's inside `192.168.0.0/16`. If you're exhausting that with webservers, it might be time to look at switching to a different IP block such as `172.16.0.0/12`

Comment: The /16 is very big broadcast domain. These days we normally use virtualization, like VMWARE technology. A single switch port can support multiple IPs. But still the number requires around 70 switches for the entire domain, assuming a switch port can support ~20 VMs, and it is 48-port switch. Is there a real life example scaling out network this way?